# Google Contact API Picture Data, returns data, but I dont know how to display it with PHP

Tags: php, image, oauth, contacts

I am using OAuth 1.0, I am getting the contacts just fine. Next I fetch an image using the link that is in the contact info. If the user has an image the request works and return a bunch of data. When I echo it I get something like this:

```
       "" ÿÀ``"ÿÄÿÄ<!"12A#Qq‘BRa3‚’±Ñðbrƒ¡Â$%¢³ÿÄÿÄ#!1Q"AaqÿÚ?ôÌìç™pzõWoÂ~vïD±èÐvQNl/ÂžåÐìMCÀƒÚüü¿ ÔLß÷&‹ðKš×aG¥=Ë È
```

Which I am assuming is the data for the image. Now that I have this, I cant figure out a way to display it.

here is an example of what I am doing:

```
$consumer = new OAuth($key,$secret);

$image = $consumer->fetch($theImageUrl);
return $image;
```

The request is working, theres no 400,401, or 404 errors.

I tried doing this already:

```
<img src="/art/transperantimage.png" style='background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,<?=$image ?>) repeat-x bottom'/>
```

and I just ended up with more data jibberish.

I guess my question is how the heck to I display this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the documentation, this request returns the bytes of the image. So you have three options:

1. Write a PHP script that outputs those bytes (and only those bytes) directly to the client using the appropriate `Content-Type` header, which is what @Prowla has in mind. Then point to this script in your `<img src="...">`.
2. Write the bytes to a publicly-accessible file on your web server, and then put the URL of that file in your `<img src="...">`.
3. Use a data URI, which you seem to have attempted, but forgot that you need to Base64 encode the data first, e.g.:

   ```php
   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode( $image ); ?>" />
   ```

While #3 is looks the simplest, #2 is probably the best solution since the image likely doesn't change very often so there's no sense requesting it from the API every single time someone reloads your page. You can just write the image to a file if the file doesn't already exist, and then periodically (e.g. every day or week) check to see if there is a new image and if there is, overwrite the old one.

Comment: Going with #3, we already discussed saving the images into the db and decided against it. thanks for the tip about the base64_encode, couldn't figure out why I was getting gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing out the image set the header content type to something like (depending on the data type):

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: That works for one, but I need to do all of a user's contacts. And I think the URL's in the contact request change after the timestamp expires, becuase I got 404's when I saved the address into a src='/getimages?fetch=<?=$contactURL?>'

Comment: That line just sets the content header. You would need to build the dynamic request URLs appropriately as you have been, make the request and print the data (the echo sample you gave) with the content type set. Also save these images on your side along with an expiration date (like suggested by Jordan)